# Java CSV import regex help needed

Tags: java

I have used many different regex strings, all of them do the same thing.

One line of my .csv looks like this:

"999","Location","Alt. fare key","Table ID","Address","Line 2","City","State",19111,,,H,,, etc......(there are 139 columns.

As you can see, some of the entries are separated by quotation marks while others are not.
Also, quotation marks or not. Every entry is separated by a comma.

Here are two examples of regex strings that I've used:

```
String regex = "(?:(?<=\")([^\"]*)(?=\"))|(?<=,|^)([^,]*)(?=,|$)"
Object[] tokens = strLine.split(regex);
model.addRow(tokens);
jTable1.setModel(model);
```

and

```
String regex = ",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)"
Object[] tokens = strLine.split(regex);
model.addRow(tokens);
jTable1.setModel(model);
```

Both of these do the same thing.

Pretending the |(s) below are the lines of my jTable:

"999"|"Location"|"Alt. fare key"|"Table ID"|"Address"|"Line 2"|"City"|"State"|19111| | |H|

I want it to come out like this:

999|Location|Alt. fare key|Table ID|Address|Line 2|City|State|19111| | |H| etc.....

What else does the regex need to remove the unwanted parenthesis?

Thanks in advance for help.
JB

Comment: Are you absolutely positive that you need regex to parse a tokenized format? Why don't you just use a simple CSV parser? It would be a many more robust approach. There are a bunch of existing ones. Even more, you can write your own in less than 30 lines after having read the [RFC4180](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180) which is fairly simple.

Comment: My Code for import the CSV is:: try {
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                        String strLine;
                        
                        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)
                        {
                            
                            Object[] tokens = strLine.split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");
                            model.addRow(tokens);
                        }
                        jTable1.setModel(model);
                        jTable1.setAutoCreateColumnsFromModel(true);

Comment: So to break that jumble paragraph down.

Comment: buffered reader to string.
string to Object via .split(regex)
and object to new row in a loop.

can you give me an example of a precompiled library that is more efficient.

Comment: The reason I am looking for a regex to parse the data is because It works with files that don't have the annoying quotation marks.

Comment: But it doesn't work with files that have the quotation marks simply because those are not regular.

Answer (score 0):

But does it handle embedded commas? the [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) library will and you just do this (copied form opencsv doc):

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("yourfile.csv"));
String [] nextLine;
while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
    // nextLine[] is an array of values from the line
    System.out.println(nextLine[0] + nextLine[1] + "etc...");
}
```

Comment: Can you help with another issue?

Comment: I am using a listSelectionModel to add data from Specific cells in the selected row to specific jtextfields. This works when all the values in the row are filled out. When the row is blank or has blanks and then gets selected it throws a NullPointerException and nothing works right. Is there another way to add the data to the text fields from the table?

Comment: This should be another top-level question. But it sounds like you are not checking for null when setting the test field.

Comment: Okay, I used an statement to check if the value was = ""; this code seams to get jumped over. I'll start a new thread when I get that far. Thought maybe there were other methods.